# OpenWeatherMap casting arraylist to Map

Tags: java, json, api

I am using a openweatherMap api for my project.The idea is to get current weather of any place.I used gson to convert json file and everything seems to work correctly.i am trying to get the "description" of the current weather from the json file,but it's stored in arraylist and so i get the error that arraylist can't be cast as map and i am unable to figure out this problem without major changes in the program

This is json file i am trying to parse:
https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

Everything works fine with main and wind information from json file,but doesn't work with weather because it's arraylist.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.reflect.*;

public class DailyForecst  {   

   public static Map<String,Object> jsonToMap(String str){
    Map<String,Object> map = new Gson().fromJson(str,new 
 TypeToken<HashMap<String,Object>> () {}.getType());
    return map;
    }

   public static void  main(String[] args) {

      String API_KEY = "16 digit Private Key";
      String LOCATION = "fresno,us";
      String urlString = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + LOCATION + "&appid=" + API_KEY + "&units=imperial";



      try{

          StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
          URL url = new URL(urlString);
          URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (conn.getInputStream()));
          String line;
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
              result.append(line);
          }

          rd.close();
          System.out.println(result);

          Map<String, Object > respMap = jsonToMap (result.toString());
          Map<String, Object > mainMap = jsonToMap (respMap.get("main").toString());
          Map<String, Object > windMap = jsonToMap (respMap.get("wind").toString());

         Map<String, Object> weatherMap = (Map<String, Object>) respMap.get("weather");

         // Map<String, Object > weatherMap = jsonToMap (respMap.get("weather").toString());



          System.out.println("Location: " + LOCATION);
          System.out.println("Current Temperature: " + mainMap.get("temp")  );
          System.out.println("Current Humidity: " + mainMap.get("humidity")  );
          System.out.println("Max: " + mainMap.get("temp_min")  );
          System.out.println("Min: " + mainMap.get("temp_max")  );
          System.out.println("Desc: " + weatherMap.get("description")  );

          System.out.println("Wind Speed: " + windMap.get("speed")  );
          System.out.println("Wind Angle: " + windMap.get("deg")  );


      }catch (IOException e){
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }



}
}
```

I tried to do the same way as i did for main and wind :             Map weatherMap = jsonToMap (respMap.get("weather").toString()); .But i got errors:

////java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3 path $[0]

So i tried to not convert json to Map rather directly use map like Map weatherMap = (Map) respMap.get("weather"); but i got

////java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map